# Magento : Loading all products like Pinterest Customize Homepage

Tags: php, ajax, magento, pinterest

I'm using magento AccessShop free theme. I want to customize my homepage like pinterest where all products will be on homepage with ajax load. Is there any way to do so using current theme using core php or any other way?
Thanks

Comment: Not with **core php** ... You need to update the template to include some javascript routine to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Open magento admin-dashboard, go to CMS -> Manage pages and add the below code in the WYSIWYG editor

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: This will get me all products but how should I arrange those in ajaxLoad sort of system on customize html page which should look like Pinterest where on scroll more products will be loaded (Tile sort of thing)

Comment: first display all the products on the home page,later apply jquery to display more products on scroll down